# $2\cdot x^n\cdot y^n \equiv -1$ mod $p$ is not true

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that this congruence can never be true:
For every prime $p=2n+1$ , $n$ a positive integer , we can find integers $x, y$ such that:

$$2\,x^n\,y^n \equiv -1 \mod p$$

Comment: Are $x,y$ arbitary integers ?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: Modulo $p$ the power $x^n$ is congruent to one of $0,1,-1$. The same applies to $y^n$. It looks like this congruence can NEVER be true unless $p=3$. The l.h.s. is one of $0,\pm2$.

Comment: Alex.P. Please check that amWhy's edit is correct. I suspect it is, but only because that makes for a more interesting question. We may have mutilated the question with that edit (I say "we" because I endorse her edit). As others pointed out, the first version was kinda trivial.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why is $x^n$  congruent to one of $0, 1, -1$? Ok, thanks for your hint.

Comment: If $x\equiv0$ the so is $x^n$. Otherwise, by Little Fermat, $x^{2n}=x^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$. Therefore $p$ divides $x^{2n}-1=(x^n-1)(x^n+1)$ so $p$ divides either $x^n-1$ or $x^n+1$. In the former case $x^n\equiv1$, in the latte $x^n\equiv-1$. If you have covered *primitive roots modulo a prime*, you can use that instead (and properties of cyclic groups).

Comment: The true statement is that that if $n>1$ the congruence is never true. You may want to edit the question to that form (if it is at all in line with your original intent).

Comment: Alex P. A conjecture that concerns you is a universal statement.  It is a claim about what always holds.  The negation of (it always holds) is "it is not the case that (it always holds)", meaning that "it does not always hold" (it may hold sometimes, but not always).  That is not equivalent to "it never holds".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How can I use primitive roots modulo a prime?

Comment: If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ and  neither $x$ nor $y$ is divisible by $p$, then $x^n$ and $y^n$ are both powers of $g^n$. But, $g^n$ is of order two so $g^n\equiv-1$. Therefore $x^n$ and $y^n$ are powers of $-1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks a looooot!

Comment: Sorry, but there is a case in which the conjecture holds: for $n=1$, $p=3$ choose $x=y=1$.  Hence it is not true that the conjecture never holds:  $$2(1^1)(1^1) \equiv -1 \mod 3 \iff 2+1 \equiv 0\mod 3$$  @Jyrki, you rendered the question, as did the OP, earlier, trivial again.

Comment: @amWhy True. I just want the OP to confirm the current (or any other formulation). We need $n>1$ for it to be true, but I'm reluctant to edit it further without a green light from the OP. Sorry about rolling back your edit. I just felt that the OP was making progress with their formulation. Some details are apparently lost in translation (those can be tricky).

Comment: The question in the title differs from that in the main body.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on here. I only rolled back the last suggested edit as it clearly changed the question $x^ny^n$ is just not $(xy)^{2n}$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier yes that was a suggested edit that I just undid.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n = 2$, $p = 5$.  Then $2 x^2 y^2 \in \{0,2,3\} \pmod{5}$.  This is because the quadratic residues modulo $5$ are $\{0, 1, -1\}$ and $2$ multiplied by any sequence of elements of $\{0,\pm 1\}$ is in $\{0,\pm 2\}$.

Comment: All: The exact formulation of the question was originally in doubt. It is still not 100% clear whether it is in a final form. Please take that into account when voting on all answers. This does also underline the perils of answering an unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quivalent to:

$$\,2(x \cdot y)^{k}+1 \equiv 0 \mod (k+1)$$
Where $k+1$ is **prime** and $k=2n$

Which would only have solution when:

$$\,(x \cdot y)^{2n} \equiv n \mod p$$

**Trivial Solution:** When $x \cdot y = 1$ and $n=1$. Hence have a solution when $p=3$

Now let $x \cdot y = a$, so that the following is true:

$$a^{p-1} \equiv n \mod p$$

We have two cases:

**a. *a* is divisible by p:** This would imply  $a^{p-1} \equiv 0 \mod p$ which is the first contradiction.

**b. *a* is NOT divisible by p:** By Fermat's Little Theorem, this would imply  $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ which is the second and final contradiction.

**Conclusion:** Your question is always true for $p>3$. That is
$$2\,x^n\,y^n \equiv -1 \mod p$$ is always NOT TRUE when $p>3$

Answer (score 0):

Take $p=5$ Note for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ then $x^2,y^2 \in \{0,\pm 1\}$

$$2x^ny^n= \begin{cases} 
0 & \mod 5\\
2 & \mod 5\\ 
-2 & \mod 5\\
\end{cases}$$

Since none of the options are equal to $-1 \mod 5$ the stated equation cannot be true for $p=5$

Comment: I think you need to check whether there exist integers $x, y$ such that $2x^ny^n \equiv -1 \pmod 5$.

Comment: well that wasn't what your comments above said. Edit the problem I'll delete my answer

Comment: All: The exact formulation of the question was originally in doubt. It is still not 100% clear whether it is in a final form. Please take that into account when voting on all answers. This does also underline the perils of answering an unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to never be true, unless $p=3$:

Assume that $2(xy)^n\equiv_p -1$, then $$4(xy)^{2n}\equiv_p 1$$ Since $2n=p-1$ we have $$4\cdot 1\equiv_p 1$$ Which holds when $p=3$.

Comment: All: The exact formulation of the question was originally in doubt. It is still not 100% clear whether it is in a final form. Please take that into account when voting on all answers. This does also underline the perils of answering an unclear question.